# get value from list tuple in haskell

Tags: haskell

These are my haskell lists

```
lst1 = ["a,","b","c"]  
lst2 = [("a","123"),("b","345")]
```

I want to get a element from "lst1" and compare with "lst2" and if the value is exist want to replace with the second value in tuple replace the 2nd  value.

so it's like this
lst1 had "a" and "b" so output should be ["123","345","c"]
so how can I do this in haskell?
pls help me
Can i do it in any other way??
thankxx!

Comment: Is it homework? Then add "homework" tag.

Comment: I hope it's not homework, since I gave a reply. By the way, you probably have a typo in lst1 (extra comma), and in lst2 (missing ])

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe

lst1 = ["a","b","c"]
lst2 = [("a","123"),("b","345")]

-- For each value of lst1, you want to replace it by something, so you'll be using map '
res = map comb lst1

-- For performance, we convert the 2nd list to a map
m = M.fromList lst2

-- For a value of lst1, you want to find it in the map, 
-- and return the result if found, 
-- or keep the original if not found
comb v = fromMaybe v (M.lookup v m)
```

Prelude> :r

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( t.hs, interpreted )

Ok, modules loaded: Main.

*Main> res

Loading package array-0.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.

Loading package containers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.

["123","345","c"]

*Main>

Comment: Thanxx,This is working fine,Can't we do this normal recursive way?

Comment: of course you can, just look at the definition of map : http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#map

Comment: @123Ex, "the normal recursive way" is not quite right.  As functional programmers get more experienced, they usually use *less* recursion, delegating the recursive parts of their functions to `map`, `foldr`, etc.  There is a saying, "recursion is the goto of functional programming".  Though it's not quite as stigmatized...

Answer (score 2):

```
map (\x -> maybe x snd $ find ((x ==).fst) lst2) lst1
```

For longer lists you should consider using a Map instead of lst2

[Edit]

```
import Data.Maybe
subst lst1 lst2 = map (\x -> fromMaybe x $ lookup x lst2) lst1
```

(Thanks to Chuck)

And just for some pointless fun:

```
import Data.Maybe
main = print $ subst [("a","123"),("b","345")] ["a","b","c"] 
subst = map.app fromMaybe lookup   
        where app f g x y = f y $ g y x
```

The perfect example for easy to write and really hard to understand (at least for me) Haskell code, so I would definitely use one of the other definitions.

Comment: Thnx, but gives an error telling "unexpected backslash (lamda)"

Comment: I tried it again in ghci, and it works fine (forgot the `import Data.List`, though). Of course in a real program you either need to call this in some function with the right args, or you can make it a function itself, e.g. `subst lst1 lst2 = map...`

Comment: Just a suggestion for brevity: `maybe x snd $ find ((x ==).fst) lst2` is precisely equivalent to `maybe x id $ lookup x lst2`.